# OpenCV, Python: How to stitch two images of different sizes and transparent backgrounds

Tags: python, image, opencv, computer-vision, feature-detection

I've been working on a project where I stitch together images from a drone flying in a lawn mower pattern. I am able to stitch together images from a single pass (thanks to many answers on stackoverflow) but when I try to stitch two separate passes together laterally, the transformation my method produces is nonsensical. Here are the two images I am trying to stitch:

[image]
[image]

And here is the code that I've been using to estimate a homography between the two, `base` and `curr`.

```
base_gray = cv2.cvtColor(base, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)
curr_gray = cv2.cvtColor(curr, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2GRAY)

detector = cv2.ORB_create()
base_keys, base_desc = detector.detectAndCompute(base_gray, None)
curr_keys, curr_desc = detector.detectAndCompute(curr_gray, None)

FLANN_INDEX_LSH = 6
flann_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_LSH,
                    table_number = 12,
                    key_size = 20,
                    multi_probe_level = 2)
search_params = dict(checks=100)
matcher = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(flann_params, search_params)
matches = matcher.match(base_desc, curr_desc)

max_dist = 0.0
min_dist = 100.0

for match in matches:
    dist = match.distance
    min_dist = dist if dist < min_dist else min_dist
    max_dist = dist if dist > max_dist else max_dist

good_matches = [match for match in matches if match.distance <= 10 * min_dist ]

base_matches = []
curr_matches = []
for match in good_matches:
    base_matches.append(base_keys[match.queryIdx].pt)
    curr_matches.append(curr_keys[match.trainIdx].pt)

bm_final = np.asarray(base_matches)
cm_final = np.asarray(curr_matches)

# find perspective transformation using the arrays of corresponding points
transformation, hom_stati = cv2.findHomography(cm_final, bm_final, method=cv2.RANSAC, ransacReprojThreshold=1)
```

As I said, it doesn't work. Is it because the transparent backgrounds are messing with the calculation?

Comment: Hi, @Victor I am working on same project as you mentioned in your question. I need to stitch drone images together to form orthomosaic/NDVI image of that. I am trying to achieve that since many days but not able to get perfect solution. My stitch result shows black lines and have stitch effect like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68257182/opencv-remove-black-corners-before-stitching Could you please help/guide me by sharing your solution? Kindly help me out? looking forward for your reply. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Flann is probably not what you want to use for matching here. First, indeed, since you're converting to grayscale, the black spots, the edges of the images, etc will likely be included in your feature set, which you do not want. Secondly, Flann uses methods to build specific descriptors for fast searching through an image database; it is used for [CBIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-based_image_retrieval), not for homography estimation.

Instead, just take a normal approach with `SIFT` or `SURF` or `ORB` or `BRISK`. Note that all of those allow to add a `mask` for their keypoint detection step, so that you can create a mask from the alpha channel to ignore keypoints in. See the OpenCV docs for [`SIFT` and `SURF`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/xfeatures2d/doc/nonfree_features.html) and for [`ORB` and `BRISK`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html) for more.

Comment: On point. Used a mask to ignore transparent/black areas, and used `BruteForce-Hamming` feature detector rather than flann with much better results.

Comment: @user2457666 glad it worked out! Your pipeline is starting to shape up nicely.

Comment: @VictorOdouard after you used BruteForce-Hamming feature detector did you try and stitch the images after that ?

Comment: Yes. The results are good but there is still quite a noticeable seam. I am currently building opencv with surf and sift to see if those feature detectors work better, and then I will use another feature matcher, `cv2.BFMatcher()` on setting `cv2.NORM_L2`.

Comment: @AnandSonawane there is also the image stitching class in OpenCV which does blending.